# How can I find the gained points per game?

Tags: rating, statistics, elo

In [another post](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/2886/167) it was written that for games played during the 2013 World Championship match, Carlsen gained 3.7 points if he wins, Anand gained 6.3 points if he wins, and that in a draw Carlsen lost 1.3 points that Anand gained.
How were these numbers arrived at?

Answer (score 4):

By "points" you probably mean rating "points". Rating is a measure of player's strength, not a prize for their performance. To me, talking about "gaining rating points" sounds a bit wrong. A player's rating increases if he wins and decreases if he loses. In the case of a draw, player's rating moves closer to his opponent's rating (or does not change if the rating difference is small).

Here's how the Elo system works:

The result of a game is 1 for a win, 0.5 for a draw, and 0 for a loss. The expected score of a player A against player B is a function of their rating difference. For FIDE ratings, see the tables in Section 8 [here](http://www.fide.com/component/handbook/?id=161&view=article). After a tournament or a match, the rating is then updated using the formula

(new rating) = (old rating) + K * (result - expected result),

where in the FIDE system K=30 for players with few games, K=10 for players whose rating has been above 2400, and K=15 for other players.

If player A's expected score is E, then player B's expected score is 1-E. Thus,
when two players play against each other e.g. in a match and their K-factor is equal, one can easily see player A's rating increases by the same amount player B's rating decreases.

For more information, see e.g. the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system).

Answer (score 2):

Two links for convenience:

- [FIDE Rating Change calculator](http://ratings.fide.com/calculator_rtd.phtml)
- [FIDE Initial Rating calculator (Rating performance)](http://ratings.fide.com/calculator_rp.phtml)